Theoritical: ROS2 vs microROS without ros2_control in the urdf for 3 motors robot to be migrated from ros1 to ros2
I am migrating a project from ROS1 to ROS2, and the original project uses an arduino to control 3 motors, the adrunio code subscribes to the joint states and uses that info to transform it to steps/second to feed to the 3 stepper mottors.
Now, the first thing i saw online is to use a hardware interface and a ros2 control tag in the urdf, and I have to create my own hardware interface, since most hardware interfaces that i find are for wheeled robots and such. My 3 motors just controls 3 prismatic joints in the x,y,z axes.
This sounds very complicated when i checked how to create a hardware interface and connect it to arduino. I found out that I could also use microROS with specific boards to establish to communication.
I am not sure which is better to use, and which one can be implemented faster?

That depends on your control stack, which controller do you use on top of the "hardware interface" (independent of the implementation)? Do you use motion planning on top of that, MoveIt2 for example?
Have a look at the ros2_control demos or this blog entry, writing a simple hardware component with serial communication to your arduino is not that time consuming.
Other features of ros2_control:

Real-time: might not be an issue here, because the arduino for sure is slower than what you can achieve by a pure topic-based communication.
Simulator integrations: Will you use gazebo (classic)?
Lifecycle of hardware and controllers (depends on your needs)


Thank you.
Yes, I will use moveit2 for path planning. I am not sure what do you mean by which controller do I use.
I have 2 versions of my project, my simulation version in which I am using Gazebo, I am using ros2_control in my urdf with GazeboSystem as the plugin. But my problem arises when I am using the URDF of my actual robot. when I run the physcial robot, I will not run Gazebo, I will only run RVIZ to control my robot. I have checked the ros2_control_demos, I failed to extract a way to create this hardware interface.

This example exactly outlines the switch between simulation and hardware.
